# Facebook SDK publishing video with feed_targeting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Had anyone succeed to publish a video with feed_targeting to a facebook page using the facebook graph api? (v2.1/me/videos).

For me is always publishing the video as public and it doesn't take in account the feed_targeting that I sent it to api. For publishing a photo or status with feed_targeting it works fine.

Comment: Indeed doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I thought you can only use Feed Targeting with Pages...?

Comment: Yes indeed is for a facebook page.

Comment: But then you can't use `/me` IMHO...

Comment: Yes, I can use me. The functionality works fine, the video is published to the facebook page. But when I am adding feed_targeting as parameter to the post query, the facebook api just tolerate it internally and as result my video post is public. The web request returns a json like {id:"21846923626345"} for both situations.

Comment: So you're using a Page Access Token?

Comment: Yes, a page access token that was generated for a facebook app with the permissions: manage_page, +all. The permissions aren't a problem because I can publish a photo or status post that has feed_targeting. Also I can publish a video with targeting (that is different from feed_targeting)

Comment: I have the same issue, and Facebook C# SDK doesn't work either, I can specify the targeting (which results in feed_targeting AND privacy/gating, while I only wan't feed_targeting) but feed_targeting 'ALONE' fails to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that at this moment facebook graph api v2.1 doesn't support feed_targeting for videos.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/videos